# Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator

Tags: search, spservices, crawling

My sharepoint site is displaying this error when I search something

[image]

I have tried deleting and creating a new search application but the problem still persists. I have also tried tried this tutorial [Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.](http://moresharepoints.blogspot.co.ke/2015/07/search-has-encountered-problem-that.html) But nothing is working for me.

Assistance of any kind will be appreciated,

Regards.

Comment: Check this service is running or not "Search Host Controller Service". CA -> System Settings -> Manage services on server.

Comment: it's running @akbarali

Comment: Have you associated new search service with the content web application after  you have recreated it? (sometimes it has to be done manually)

Comment: How can I achieve that? @MarekSarad

Comment: You need to navigate to the CentralAdmin-->Application Management --> Service Applications -->Configure service applications associations (CA_URL/_admin/ApplicationAssociations.aspx). From there check the default group (or custom if use it) and see if the search service application is associated.

Comment: if it correctly associated could you share the details of error from the ULS logs. When you will try it again it will create new correlation ID and you check in logs details of the error.

Comment: SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Correlation Id: 5f3ccc9d-f6f6-5032-d3bb-7820420a6e65. That is what I'm getting when I search the  new correlation ID using  Stefan Gordon's SharePoint ULS Log Viewer

Comment: But what is the message of that entry with this correlation?

Comment: Is your search site collection associated with a web application that is part of the proxy group containing the Search Service Application?

Comment: Yes @MatthewMcDermott ...  When I go to Central admin> application management> Manage service applications > Configure service application associations.. Then clicking on my site collection for example http://nicholas.gov:987/ .....I get Search Service Application Proxy
is checked..

Comment: @MarekSarad the error is SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Correlation Id: b091cc9d-26bf-5032-d3bb-723c0e5f799b

Comment: And what is in the logs related to that Correlation ID?

Answer (score 0):

if SharePoint runs on windows server 2019, when probably the search issue can be resolved according to this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-errors-windows-server-2019

"Workaround

To work around this problem, create a rule that allows **port 808** for any application under Inbound rules by using the following steps:

In the Windows Server Start menu, type Windows Firewall. (Or open Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall.)
Select Advanced Settings in the left-hand pane, and then Inbound Rules.
In the Actions pane on the right, select New Rule.
In the New Rule wizard, select Port and then select Next.
Select the TCP check box, select the Specific local ports check box, enter 808, and then select Next.
Select Allow the connection and then select Next.
Select which profiles to apply the rule to. (The default is to have all three selected.)
Enter a rule name and select Finish."